# Deployment issue(at Heroku), getting promise rejected but the code is running fine locally -NodeJS/React

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, heroku, deployment

I am facing an issue of retrieving data from the server at `Heroku`. it was all working fine when using `localhost`. After deployment on `Heroku` all `POST/GET` requests are working fine just one of the `Get` request is coming up as `pending/reject`, but cant understand why exactly.

I have a feeling that it might be to do with environment variables and tried to tweak few bits without success. i am not sure what else i can do. Any thought or pointer please.

**Update-1** I have finally resolved the issue but dont understand the logic behind it, so basically i first changed the url from `(/api/:abc)` to `(/api/x1)` and then change the request to POST and   retrieve the data in `body` rather then `url` but still at that point i had the same issue, then i came across a post saying the special character might not work in Heroku environment so i delete the regression expression `re = /(?<=^...)(.*)/` and used another compare logic with my data and now i am able to see the results, but dont understand why the regression expression was causing the issue.

-`Link to  Heroko app` when i try to select from dropdown button `(e.g select Eco-yogaMats )` i am facing the `error` [link to App](https://yogaoutlet.herokuapp.com/)

- `FrontEnd` snippet code in ReactJs

```
     function tabsearch(selection) {
     let selection1 = `/#/${selection}`;
        let customerSelection = encodeURIComponent(selection1);
        console.log(customerSelection);
        let url = `/api/${customerSelection}`;
        // this request make the http request format
        let request = new Request(url);
    
        (async () => {
          let tabsearchback = await fetch(request)
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
    
              console.log("70bew", res);
              let y = res.json();
              console.log(y);
              return y;
            })
            .then((data1) => {
              setHomepage(data1);
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
console.log(err) // here the error shows: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
 setHomepage(undefined))}; //  
    
          setShowPage(1);
        })();
      }
```

- `Backend` snippet of Server code

```
  

      app.get("/api/:abc", (req, res) => {
              console.log("NEwwwww");// this is not showing up either when i heroku logs --tailuse , it may indicate if it is not hitting the API here either
          const decoded = { key1: req.params.abc };
          let re = /(?<=^...)(.*)/;
        let decoded_refine = decoded.key1.match(re);
        connection.query(
            "SELECT product_name,producNumber,price,productDescription,image_URL,stockQuantity FROM main_Products_sub_category  INNER JOIN main_Product_Info INNER JOIN images ON main_Products_sub_category.main_Products_sub_category_id= main_Product_Info.main_Products_sub_category_main_Products_sub_category_id AND main_Product_Info.producInfoId=images.main_Product_Info_producInfoId WHERE main_Products_sub_category.main_Products_sub_category_name= ?",
            [decoded_refine[0]],
            function (err, results) {
         if (err) {
                let new1 = new Error("Doesnt exist");
                res.send(new1);
              } else {
                let results1 = JSON.stringify(results);
                 res.send(results1);
          }
            }
          );
        });
```

- `Log at server side` when using the command   `heroku logs --tail`

```
    2020-08-18T22:26:32.038933+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/%2F%23%2FEco-YogaMats" host=yogaoutlet.herokuapp.com request_id=53a6a549-2cf5-4130-86ea-cf46f1ed9e67 fwd="94.173.211.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=3670 protocol=https
```

- `Crome console` showing promise rejected

[image: ment]

-`Home display`  reduce is used here as part of initial quatitiy against the products fetched from the `DB`

```
function Home({ props, addBasketitems }) {
 let initialQuantities = props.reduce((quantities, product) => ({ ...quantities, [product.product_name]: 0 }), {});
```

Comment: From the stacktrace that you posted, I can say you are calling a function `reduce` on an undefined object in `homeDisplay.js` line 12

Comment: Hi, yes you right ,i have updated the code above to reflect the reduce. it is basically used to stored the initial values of the products thats fetched from the back end, it all working fine when i use on local machine, another interesting point i notice that the console in `server side ` `  console.log("NEwwwww");` is not showing either when i run command `heroku logs --tail` it indicate it not even hitting the API at backend(but i am getting response of status 200) but i am not sure.

Comment: i have just tried to catch the error at front end (updated above code), it shows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` but i am using `json.stringify(..)` backend so i am not sure why it is coming up this error.

Comment: I have finally resolved the issue but dont understand the logic behind it, so basically i first changed the url from `(/api/:abc)` to `(/api/x1)` and then change the request to POST and   retrieve the data in `body` rather then `url` but still at that point i had the same issue, then i came across a post saying the special character might not work in Heroku environment so i delete the regression expression `re = /(?<=^...)(.*)/` and used another compare logic with my data and now i am able to see the results, but dont understand why the regression expression was causing the issue.